# Where are mongo replication settings stored?

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set

After a complete reinstall of mongo, it has still remembered the replica set configuration from before; where has it stored this?

I installed mongo on a linux server, using our project's user account, into a directory owned by that user.  I set up replication and had it working fine.  Then, to test out some finer install points, I removed the whole mongo directory and did a reinstall.  Entering into mongo, I found that the replication was already set up as before; so it would appear that mongo is storing the information somewhere.

I have checked several areas which might have been holding the replica set config:

1. First, in the mongo directory, but that was deleted.
2. In some traditional linux structure probably owned by root, but the project user does not have root access and mongo, run by the same, should not either.
3. The project user's home directory.  Now this does have a .dbshell file containing the command line history, but only that.  I did not see any other files there that related.
4. Some location specified in the mongo configuration.  But I only have two paths mentioned in there, one for the system log (`systemLog.path`) and the other for storage (`storage.dbPath`), and the both point to the mongo directory, which was deleted.

Does anyone know where mongo is storing this configuration information?

Comment: A good starting point would be rs.help() and rs.status() in your Mongo Shell.

rs.conf() shows your current replication config.

Comment: Actually, rs.status() is how I know that it came up with all the original information.  Unfortunately, it provides no information on what physical location on the machine that the information is stored.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The replication data is stored in the [local database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/local-database/) in each node (as of MongoDB 3.2.9). This database contains information about the replica set, and also contains the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) (the `oplog.rs` collection). The replica set information is stored in the `system.replset` collection in this `local` database.

The physical files for this database (and also for other databases) are stored in the [dbPath directory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-data-directory), which can be configured using:

- The `--dbpath` parameter when starting `mongod`
- The `storage.dbPath` setting in the [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath)

The default `dbpath` value is `/data/db`

Your replica set setting will not be retained if you emptied the `dbpath` directory. If you find that the replication settings are being retained, it is possible that the `dbpath` setting is incorrect.

Comment: I wasn't clear above, but I am setting the `dbPath` which is in the mongo directory that I am deleting.  BUT I just went through the whole process again and the rs config information was gone.  Which is what I would have expected in the first place.  Possibly I got one of the steps backwards earlier.  I am going to go ahead and check this as the right answer, since it should be, and mark this down to user error.